# How do I adjust top margin of inline graphic to align with rest of text?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, inline, height

##### What is my problem?

---

Here is the latex markdown I have for rendering my phone number

```
\textbf{(\includegraphics[width=3.0mm]{call.png})}\ 123-456-7890
```

My phone number shows up like this - the icon is just slightly raised

[image]

Here is the latex markdown I have for rendering my website url

```
\textbf{(\includegraphics[width=3.0mm]{internet.png})}\ www.example.ca
```

My website url shows up like this - the icon is just slightly raised

[image]

##### What is my question?

---

How do I add a bit of vertical margin to the tops of each `\includegraphics[...]` to properly align the images and text?

Comment: Off-topic: You could also use `\faPhone` and `\faGlobe` from the `fontawesome` package.

Comment: @rmolina How do you specify the non-filled versions of those icons? Such as for `\faEnvelope`

Comment: That would be `\faEnvelope0`. Take a look at the package documentation for the full list of names.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can raise `<stuff>` using `\raisebox{<raise>}[<height>][<depth>]{<stuff>}`. A negative `<raise>` lowers `<stuff>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  (\faPhone) 123-456-7890 &
    (\raisebox{-.2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\faPhone}) 123-456-7890 \\
  (\faGlobe) www.example.ca &
    (\raisebox{-.2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\faGlobe}) www.example.ca
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The [unfilled globe](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/globe?style=light) is available in with Fontawesome Pro. So if you have a comparable image you can use the same technique above.